# Exibir apenas uma quantidade máxima de caracteres

Tags: php, mysql, caracteres

Minha dúvida, acredito eu, é bem simples, como posso fazer para exibir apenas uma quantidade máxima de caracteres para o usuário, por exemplo, 25 caracteres + "..."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é limitar os caracteres destes textos, para que os tamanhos das div's não fiquem tão diferentes.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta... mas acho que poderia tratar na tela mesmo utilizando por exemplo o Substring do javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `SUBSTRING` para fazer a consulta retornar apenas os 25 primeiros caracteres:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col_texto, 1, 25) FROM textos;
```

Comment: isso mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: Tentei usar numa outra query de seleção, porém desta vez não rodou
`select C.id, C.card_name, C.monster_lrl, C.link_image, C.effect_description, C.card_atk, C.card_def, C.quantity, E.edition_name, E.edition_code, S.card_status_desc, A.kind_attribute, K.kind_name, M.kind_monster_name from card C inner join card_editions E on E.id = C.id_card_edition inner join kind_attributes A on A.id = C.id_kind_attributes inner join kind_card K on K.id = C.id_kind_card inner join kind_monster M on M.id = C.id_kind_monster inner join card_status S on S.id = C.id_card_status order by C.id desc limit 5`

Comment: quero usar em C.effect_description

Comment: Quando chegar na coluna `C.effect_description` tente fazer: `SUBSTRING(C.effect_description, 1, 25)`

Comment: da erro de undefined index

Comment: consegui, usei o substr na exibição `<?= substr($card['effect_description'], 0, 50) ?>`